# AIX Curl command

Tags: linux, aix, curl

I have a cURL command that I am running on RedHat 7.3 like the following:

```
curl -X POST https://myserver:443/ -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/json'-d '{ "action": "test", "ipaddress": "192.168.1.1", "value": "false", "environment": "myrealm" }' --insecure
```

I now need to do the same on AIX 7100. So far I have

```
curl -X POST -d '{ "action": "test", "ipaddress": "192.168.1.1", "value": "false", "environment": "myrealm" }' https://myserver:443
```

however i continue to get the error

```
You can only select one HTTP request!
```

When I drop the `-X POST` it runs but it isn't doing a POST anymore, it simply hangs there until cancelled. Does anyone have an idea of how I can run the first cURL command on an AIX machine?

thanks in advance!

## EDIT

I am able to establish the connection now, how can I handle a

--insecure

in AIX? That option does not exist it seems.

Comment: What happens when you add the content-type header like you have it in the first call (`-H 'content-type: application/json'`)? Also, if you add `-v` you can get more information about what's happening.

Comment: I stripped off the headers to try to isolate the issue which seems to be the -X, I am trying to do a GET now to make sure I can at least do that, but since the cert is self signed and there is no --insecure I am not getting very far.

Comment: The server will reject your request if you don't have the proper content type. It's not going to know you're sending json. And what about `-v`? What do you see?

Comment: * Closing connection #0
curl: (7) Failed to connect

Comment: That's a fundamental connectivity issue rather than a high-level curl problem. For example, DNS or firewall misconfiguration. What happens when you put that address in a browser, for instance (on the AIX host)? Or try `netcat <addr> 443` or `nc <addr> 443` if you have netcat but no browser on that machine.

Comment: It turns out it was a firewall issue that I resolved. how can I get around the self signed cert error?

Comment: Every version of curl I've seen has `-k` / `--insecure`. What can you find in `man curl` about TLS/SSL? (What version of curl _are_ you using? `curl -V` ... capital V in this case)

Comment: curl 7.9.3 (powerpc-ibm-aix5.3.0.0) libcurl 7.9.3 (OpenSSL 0.9.8y) (ipv6 enabled)

Comment: That's over 15 years old! You need to update that...otherwise you might not be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah welcome to my hell. I'll see if I'm allowed to update cURL. think wget might do it?

Comment: Tell your admins that the tools you're using are completely obsolete and preventing you from doing your job! `wget` might work but are you sure you're not using a 15 year old version of that. ;)

Comment: We have a handful of these old servers, but unfortunately i need to write the script to work on all of them :(. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck.

Comment: https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html has 7.53.1